# Issue with POSIX thread synchronization and/or pthread_create() argument passing

Tags: c++, multithreading, semaphore

I am trying to create a number of different threads that are required to wait for all of the threads to be created before they can perform any actions. This is a smaller part of a large program, I am just trying to take it in steps. As each thread is created it is immediately blocked by a semaphore. After all of the threads have been created, I loop through and release all the threads. I then wish each thread to print out its thread number to verify that they all waited. I only allow one thread to print at a time using another semaphore.

The issue I'm having is that although I create threads #1-10, a thread prints that it is #11. Also, a few threads say they have the same number as another one. Is the error in my passing the threadID or is it in my synchronization somehow?

Here is relevant code:

```
//Initialize semaphore to 0. Then each time a thread is spawned it will call
    //semWait() making the value negative and blocking that thread. Once all of the
    //threads are created, semSignal() will be called to release each of the threads
     sem_init(&threadCreation,0,0);


     sem_init(&tester,0,1);


    //Spawn all of the opener threads, 1 for each valve
    pthread_t threads[T_Valve_Numbers];
    int check;

    //Loop starts at 1 instead of the standard 0 so that numbering of valves
    //is somewhat more logical. 
    for(int i =1; i <= T_Valve_Numbers;i++)
    {
        cout<<"Creating thread: "<<i<<endl;
        check=pthread_create(&threads[i], NULL, Valve_Handler,(void*)&i);
        if(check)
        {
            cout <<"Couldn't create thread "<<i<<" Error: "<<check<<endl;
            exit(-1);
        }
    }

    //Release all of the blocked threads now that they have all been created
    for(int i =1; i<=T_Valve_Numbers;i++)
    {
        sem_post(&threadCreation);
    }

    //Make the main process wait for all the threads before terminating
    for(int i =1; i<=T_Valve_Numbers;i++)
    {
        pthread_join(threads[i],NULL);
    }
    return 0;



}   
    void* Valve_Handler(void* threadNumArg)
    {   
        int threadNum = *((int *)threadNumArg);
        sem_wait(&threadCreation);//Blocks the thread until all are spawned

        sem_wait(&tester);
        cout<<"I'm thread "<<threadNum<<endl;
        sem_post(&tester);
    }
```

When T_Valve_Numbers = 10, some sample output is:

```
Creating thread: 1
Creating thread: 2
Creating thread: 3
Creating thread: 4
Creating thread: 5
Creating thread: 6
Creating thread: 7
Creating thread: 8
Creating thread: 9
Creating thread: 10
I'm thread 11   //Where is 11 coming from?
I'm thread 8
I'm thread 3
I'm thread 4
I'm thread 10
I'm thread 9
I'm thread 7
I'm thread 3
I'm thread 6
I'm thread 6   //How do I have 2 6's?
```

OR

```
Creating thread: 1
Creating thread: 2
Creating thread: 3
Creating thread: 4
Creating thread: 5
Creating thread: 6
Creating thread: 7
Creating thread: 8
Creating thread: 9
Creating thread: 10
I'm thread 11
I'm thread 8
I'm thread 8
I'm thread 4
I'm thread 4
I'm thread 8
I'm thread 10
I'm thread 3
I'm thread 9
I'm thread 8 //Now '8' showed up 3 times
```

"I'm thread..." is printing 10 times so it appears like my semaphore is letting all of the threads through. I'm just not sure why their thread number is messed up.

Comment: Pass the value of I, not its address, to the thread.

Comment: As I said below, I have to pass a type `void *` and my compiler will not allow me to directly cast from an int. I couldn't find/come up with any other way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
check=pthread_create(&threads[i], NULL, Valve_Handler,(void*)&i);
                                                             ^^
```

You're passing the thread start function the address of `i`. `i` is changing all the time in the main loop, unsynchronized with the thread functions. You have no idea what the value of `i` will be once the thread function gets around to actually dereferencing that pointer.

Pass in an actual integer rather than a pointer to the local variable if that's the only thing you'll ever need to pass. Otherwise, create a simple `struct` with all the parameters, build an array of those (one for each thread) and pass each thread a pointer to its own element.

Example: (assuming your thread index never overflows an `int`)

```
#include <stdint.h> // for intptr_t

...
check = pthread_create(..., (void*)(intptr_t)i);
...

int threadNum = (intptr_t)threadNumArg;
```

Better/more flexible/doesn't require `intprt_t` that might not exist example:

```
struct thread_args {
  int thread_index;
  int thread_color;
  // ...
}

// ...

struct thread_args args[T_Valve_Numbers];
for (int i=0; i<T_Valve_Numbers; i++) {
  args[i].thread_index = i;
  args[i].thread_color = ...;
}

// ...

check = pthread_create(..., &(args[i-1])); // or loop from 0, less surprising
```

A word of caution about this though: that array of thread arguments needs to stay alive at least as long as the threads will use it. In some situations, you might be better of with a dynamic allocation for each structure, passing that pointer (and its ownership) to the thread function (especially if you're going to detach the threads rather than joining them).

If you're going to join the threads at some point, keep those arguments around the same way you keep your `pthread_t` structures around. (And if you're creating and joining in the same function, the stack is usually fine for that.)

Comment: I spent probably 2 hours just trying to get i passed to my threads. pthread_create requires that I give it a type void* and if I try to directly cast my int i, I get a compilation error because of the size difference. This was the only way I could get it to not yell at me

Comment: `intptr_t` has the same size as a `void*`, so you can use that in this case. (Or `uintptr_t`.)

Comment: THANKS! That fixed it. Wish I had found that solution when I spent all that time looking yesterday.